# How do I access the information inside the response body of a postman test Get call

Tags: json, postman

Below is a JSON format from the response body

```
{
   "properties":{
      "name":"Jake",
      "id":123,
      "HashData":[
         {
            "Major":"CS",
            "code":234
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I tried using:

```
var x = pm.response.json().properties;
console.log(x.HashData); // it returned HashData is [object object] 
console.log(x.HashData.code); // it returned undefined
```

How else can I see or access the data?
And how do you use this in patch as in if you want to change code from 234 to 567?

Comment: What is `.data`? Is that part if your response but you're not showing it in the example? `HashData` is an array so you would either need to use `HashData[0].thePropertiesKey` or loop through the array. You're better off researching how to access the different parts of JSON as this isn't really a Postman specific issue.

Comment: Thank you and Sorry about that I hope the example is clear now

Comment: It's really not, could you just copy the same structure you have and replace the sensitive info with dummy values. Be aware of the formatting of the code clock too, it's quite flat in structure now so it's difficult to know what array is inside what object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the pm object. 
Try  **`console.log(x.HashData[0].code);`**
Your HasData is an **array**;

```
pm.test (
    "Response HashData has a code.",
    function()
    {
        var data = pm.response.json();
        pm.expect(data.properties.HashData[0]).to.have.property('code');

    }
);
```

This if for object but for arrays you need to use the key.

```
pm.test (
    "Response has name property.",
    function()
    {
        var data = pm.response.json();
        pm.expect(data.properties).to.have.property('name');

    }
);
```

More test documentation here : https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/scripts/postman-sandbox-api-reference/

To change the value you would do something like :

```
 data.properties.HashData[0].code = 567
```

Comment: @rohit please set as answer if this did indeed answer your question.

Comment: do you know how to change it's value in patch

Comment: Got the solution to it. Using index in path